# android how to sync onitemclicklistener listview id and database id

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview

this is a succesor to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513601/android-delete-item-listview-and-database)

At first everything worked fine but after 2 deletes the misery starts. The database entries start with ID 1, then 2 and so on. Lets say I have three database entries. The listview IDs for these three entries are 2,1 and 0.
The database entries are 1,2 and 3. 1 and 2 will be deleted with the onitemclicklistener but since the listview doesn´t have an ID 3, the corresponding database entry will never ever be deleted.

So the question is, how can I "sync" those two IDs?

**Listview-Class**

```
public class anzeigen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = anlegen.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String FILENAME = TAG + ".kdf";
    private List valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final VorgangDataSource dataSource = new VorgangDataSource(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anzeigen);

        Log.d(TAG,"Die Datenquelle wird geöffnet!");
        dataSource.open();

        final List<vorgangsdaten> vorgangsdatenList = dataSource.getAllVorgangsDaten();

        final ArrayAdapter<vorgangsdaten> VorgangArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                R.layout.mylistlayout,
                vorgangsdatenList
        );

        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(VorgangArrayAdapter);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s_id = String.valueOf(id);
                Log.d(s_id,"id_in_onitem");

                String p_id = String.valueOf(position);
                Log.d(p_id,"position_on_item");

                int pos = position;
                vorgangsdatenList.remove(pos);
                dataSource.deleteRow(id);
                VorgangArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        //ActionBar Costumization
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setIcon(R.drawable.search1);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dataSource.close();
    }
}
```

**deleteRow-Method:**

```
public void deleteRow(long id){

        String s_id;
        s_id = String.valueOf(id);

        Log.d(s_id,"id_value");

        database.delete(VorgangDbHelper.TABLE_VORGAENGE_LIST,VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {s_id});

        long deleteID = database.delete(VorgangDbHelper.TABLE_VORGAENGE_LIST,VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {s_id});
        String s_del = String.valueOf(deleteID);
        Log.d(s_del,"delete_row_value");

    }
```

If you need more code just let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying Bonattis answer and experimenting a little bit I found another answer.

**deleteRow-Method**

```
public void deleteRow(long id){

        String s_id;                    //String for long id
        s_id = String.valueOf(id);      //assign String value of id
        String s_rowId = null;          //String for rowid
        long rowId = 0;
        long deleteId = 0;
        String s_deleteId = null;

        Log.d(s_id,"id_value");

        Cursor cursor = database.query(VorgangDbHelper.TABLE_VORGAENGE_LIST,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            s_rowId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_ID));
            rowId = Long.parseLong(s_rowId);
            deleteId = rowId + id;
            s_deleteId = String.valueOf(deleteId);
            Log.d(s_rowId,"rowID");
            Log.d(s_deleteId,"deleteID");
        }

        database.delete(VorgangDbHelper.TABLE_VORGAENGE_LIST,VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {s_deleteId});
    }
```

How does it work now?

So the deleteRow-Method(dRM) gets the id of the first database entry (`s_rowId`) and converts it to long (`rowId`).
Now I take the `long id` passed from the listview and add it to `rowId` which is my `deleteId`. With this I have the correct database value to what I clicked in the listview and can pass it over to `database.delete`

Answer (score 1):

You have no synchronicity between your Database and the ListView items.

When selecting the data, select the ID from the table, and keep it in memory as well.

Since `vorgangsdaten` looks german or sweden, I am having trouble understanding the meaning of those words. The ListView has its own "id" for each item, to keep a list of them shown, and the rest "hidden". What you must do is have an `Object` with details that are syncronized with the database, and when a list item is clicked, the "list id" is used to query an `Object` and delete from the database.

An example would be:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> arrayListData = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayListNames = new ArrayList<>();
MyObject stuffs = database.query(); // In here, fetch the data
/* I am simplifing the MyObject to [String name, String aValue, int aNumber] */
for(MyObject s: stuffs){
   arrayListData.add(s);
   arrayListNames.add(s.name);
}
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayListNames
        );

listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        MyObject thing = arrayListData.get(position);
                        database.delete(thing.aNumber);
                    }
                }
        );
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: It´s a german word ;-) I would translate it as "eventdata"     Ok I´ll try your approach. Thx for your answer.